# Не выводит все ссылки и текст (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь вывести текст и ссылки но на выходе получаю лишь один текст одну ссылку почему если в переменой divs 2 объекта по которому должен пройтись цикл for?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Bs
import requests


headers = {'accept': '*/*',
       'user-agent': 'Your USER AGENT'}
base_url = 'https://site.com'

def function(base_url, headers):
   session = requests.Session()
   request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
   if request.status_code == 200:
       soup = Bs(request.content, 'lxml')
       divs = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'entity-seasons'})
       print(divs)
       for div in divs:
          title = div.find('a').text
          href = div.find('a')['href']
          print(title)
          print(href)
else:
    print('ERROR')

function(base_url, headers)
```

данный код выдаёт только текст-1 и example_href-1.com, а вот что выдаёт divs

```
<div class="entity-seasons">
<a class="entity-season js-entity-season is-selected" href="example_href-1.com" title="BigTitle">текст-1</a>
<a class="entity-season js-entity-season" href="example_href-2.com" title="BigTitle">текст-2</a>
</div>
```

в `<div class="entity-seasons">` могут быть и три атрибута `<a>` и мне нужно вообщем как то вытаскивать текст с ссылкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете `.find('a')`, но этот метод возвращает только один результат. Наверное вам нужен метод `.find_all()`:

```
In [66]: for div in divs:
    ...:     title = div.find('a').text
    ...:     href = div.find('a')['href']
    ...:     print(title)
    ...:     print(href)
    ...:     
текст-1
example_href-1.com

In [67]: for div in divs:
    ...:     links = div.find_all('a')
    ...:     
    ...:     for link in links:
    ...:         print(link.text, link['href'])
    ...:         
текст-1 example_href-1.com
текст-2 example_href-2.com
```

Comment: спасибо большое! Что то я не додумался до этого!